# Check Moblie Number or Not in PHP String

Tags: php, isnumeric

Iam New in PHP . I Know How to Check a String number or Not using  `is_numeric`   but   I want Check Mobile Number add `+` 
in my case

```
$mobile = "+15666886345" ;
if($mobile)  {
  //  Valid  Mobile Number
} 
else   {
// Not Valid Mobile Number
}
```

How to Check this Case

Comment: are you assuming that any phone number (that is, a dialing sequence) that starts with a `+` is a mobile number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function to match the string as like below

```
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9 +-]*$/', $mobile)){
     //  Valid  Mobile Number
}else{
     // Not Valid Mobile Number
}
```